# C# Reading From A File

Tags: c#, list

I have an assignment to read text in from a text file. The text is an inventory with department names followed by the quantity of items in the department and then items underneath the separate departments with the item name, quantity, and price. A part of the text file is shown here:

```
Stationary, 4
Notebook, 20, .99
Pens, 50, .50
Pencils, 25, 0.09
Post It Notes, 30, 4.99
Tools, 6
Band Saw, 3, 299.99
Cresent Wrench, 12, 8.49
Circular Saw, 5, 89.99
Tile Cutter, 2, 149.99
Screwdriver, 70, 2.99
Measuring Tape, 34, 10.99
```

I'm able to load the text file in just fine. My task is to take in user input for them decide which department they want to shop on. **How am I able to display just the departments and then just the items of the desired department from the user?** I have a method to output all of the departments and items shown below. This is my first time working with text files with C# so I have no idea what I am doing.

```
static void ReadDepartments(out List<Dept> s)
{
    string line;    // detail line read from file
    string[] tokens; // break line up into tokens
    string deptName;    // name of department
    int deptQuan;       // quan of different items in dept
    s = new List<Dept>();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"..\..\inventory.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >=0)
            {
                List<Item> myItemList = new List<Item>(); // new instance of tmp List
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                tokens = line.Split(',');
                deptName = tokens[0];
                deptQuan = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[1]);
                for (int i=0; i< deptQuan; i++)
                {
                    // read each line of dept and build a list of items
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    tokens = line.Split(',');
                    Item myItem = new Item(tokens[0], Convert.ToInt32(tokens[1]), Convert.ToDouble(tokens[2]));
                    myItemList.Add(myItem);
                }
                s.Add(new Dept(deptName,deptQuan, myItemList));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Can't open file because {0}", e.Message);
    }
}

static void PrintInventory(List<Dept> s)
{
    foreach (Dept d in s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dept: {0,-20} [{1} items]", d.Name, d.NumItems);
        for (int i = 0; i < d.NumItems; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("      {0,-15} {1,4} {2,7:$,##0.00}", d.GetItem(i).Name,
                d.GetItem(i).Quan, d.GetItem(i).PriceEach);
    }
}
```

I started a method to check if the desired department is a valid department shown below. **Is there an easier way to implement the valid[] variable instead of including all of the department names?** I will have to error check for valid items and that seems like it would be very tedious.

```
static string GetDepartment(string prompt)
{
    string[] valid = {"BOOKS", "FOOD", "VIDEO", "SPORTS", "STATIONARY", "TOOLS"};
    string ans = GetString(prompt, valid, "Inavlid response. Please choose a department.");
    return ans; 
}

static string GetString(string prompt, string[] valid, string error)
{
    string response;
    bool OK = false;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        foreach (string s in valid) if (response == s) OK = true;
        if (!OK) Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
    while (!OK);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Hint : Departments after Split() has two items in the array while items have three items in teh array.

Comment: @Johnny....on print method add a parameter name: user input. then add a if condition under for loop to check if the user input match your desired department name...if it matches then go for print the details...else no department. Voila Or you can use Linq but it is bit advance (as I will suggest easier solution for you now).

Comment: A suggestion would be to return an `IEnumerable<Dept>` from `ReadDepartments` instead of passing a `List`. You can use `AddRange(ReadDepartments())` instead, which wouldn't limit you to Lists in the future when reading departments.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your method that reads from the text file results in you having a `List<Dept>`. So you can generate a list of valid department names by going through the list of departments that you have read from the text file.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is great for searching through data and checking if items exists and what not.
Since you have all of your departments in a `List` you can query it via some different methods. Either search your raw data directly

```
using System.Linq;
...
List<Dept> departments;
...
departments.Any(dept => dept.Name == response);
```

Or if you want to send the names to your `GetString` method:

```
GetString(prompt, departments.Select(dept => dept.Name), ...);
...
string GetString(string prompt, IEnumerable<string> valids, string error)
...
valids.Any(valid => valid == response);
```

If you want to use the Department instead you can use `FirstOrDefault` instead (which also takes a predicate) and check for `null` if the item does not exist

```
Department found = departments.FirstOrDefault(dept => dept.Name == response);
if (found == null) //department name does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok on your code then you can add a if statement to check whether if it is your desired department info to print. I didn't check the whole code. You also can solve this problem with Linq (it will be more smart coding then) but your code seems to me as a starter code, so may be it will be a little inefficient but I hope it will solve your problem.

```
static void PrintInventory(List<Dept> s,string userInputDepartmentName)
{
    if(s == null && s.Count <= 0)
        return;

    foreach (Dept d in s)
    {
        if(d.Name.Equals(userInputDepartmentName))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Dept: {0,-20} [{1} items]", d.Name, d.NumItems);
           for (int i = 0; i < d.NumItems; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,4} {2,7:$,##0.00}", d.GetItem(i).Name,d.GetItem(i).Quan, d.GetItem(i).PriceEach);
        }
     }
}
```